# Manjaro hangs at "reached target Graphical interface" on first boot

Tags: boot, manjaro, graphics

When I try to install Manjaro on my new laptop the system just hangs on *Reached target Graphical interface* when I try and boot from the installation media.

The CPU and GPU in my laptop is a Ryzen 5 4500U and I'm using the minimal installation of Manjaro. I've seen a lot of people that have the same problem but it looks like a different problem most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I only needed to download a slightly older iso file